# How I run Swagger in SpringBoot 3.2.0?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

When I am using** springboot 3.2.0 with swagger 2.9.2 it does not work**. How i fix it **without downgrade springboot 3.2.0** verrsion?

this is my swagger config

```
package com.lifepill.possystem.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;

@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket SwaggerApi(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
    }
}
```

this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-     4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.lifepill</groupId>
<artifactId>pos-system</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>pos-system</name>
<description>POS system project with Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>



</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When i try with springboot 2.7.17 version swagger is working. But 3.2.0 verion doesn't work.
I try Spring Cores it also..

Answer (score 1):

just found the solution:

I had this dependency before migrating to 3.2.0:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.14</version>
    </dependency>
```

I had to replace it to :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

And now it is working on my side. I took the latest version available here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springdoc/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui

On your side you're still using springfox, so I do believe you can completly replace your 2 dependencies by the springdoc openapi one :)

(FYI on my side I don't have anymore the SwaggerConfig java class, not sure if this one is needed)