# SpringBoot 3.1.5 Api docs working but no data in swagger ui

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

Hi I made an Sprongbootapplication with OpenAPI. I Documented my API @Operation and so. If I call my
"springdoc.api-docs.path" I get the correct answer but if i call my "springdoc.swagger-ui.path" I get only "No API definition provided." or the default petstore.
I looked through many posts here and other sites, maybe someone can help me here.

### My Setup

My dependency for swagger:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My application.properties:

```
springdoc.api-docs.path                         =/v3/doc/api-docs
springdoc.api-docs.enabled                      =true
springdoc.swagger-ui.csrf.enabled               =false
springdoc.swagger-ui.with-credentials           =false
springdoc.swagger-ui.filter                     =false
springdoc.swagger-ui.syntax-highlight.activated =true
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled                    =true
springdoc.swagger-ui.disable-swagger-default-url=true
springdoc.swagger-ui.path                       =/v3/doc/swagger/swagger-ui.html
springdoc.packages-to-scan                      =de.my.rootPackage
```

My Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/root")
@Validated
public class MyController{
    
    private MyService myService;

    public MyController(final MyService  myService) {
        this.myService= myService;
    }
    
    @Operation(summary = "Saving data", description = "This endpoint saves a new data.")
    @Parameter(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = DataDto.class), mediaType = "application/json"))
    @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "My description", content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "201", description = "My description", content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "An invalid request was received.", content = @Content),
            @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "An internal error occurred.", content = @Content),
    })
    @PostMapping(value = "/save", consumes = TYPE_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity saveClinic(@NotNull @Valid @RequestBody final DataDto dataDto){
        //some code
    }
    
    
    
}
```

### Behavior:

Calling localhost:8080/v3/doc/api-docs --> provides json with description I defined at @ Operation and so

Calling localhost:8080/v3/doc/swagger/swagger-ui.html --> redirects to http://localhost:8080/v3/doc/swagger/swagger-ui/index.html and only displaying "No API definition provided.". If i click "explore" I get "Unable to render this definition

The provided definition does not specify a valid version field.

Please indicate a valid Swagger or OpenAPI version field. Supported version fields are swagger: "2.0" and those that match openapi: 3.0.n (for example, openapi: 3.0.0).".

Has anyone any Ideas?

I have the same configuration for swagger in another projects and that works fine.

### I tried:

- chaning the dependency version
- adding/playing with the properties
- mvn clean and rebuild
- invalidating ide caches

### Edit Notes

#### Edit 1: 25.03.2024, 07:31

I already read the post from suggested by @Mohamedaminebenhassen. The app was newly set up with spring initializr and did not have the "springdoc-openapi-ui" before. I tried the "springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui" 2.4.0 (currently newest) aswell without success. I updated the dependency and run maven clean and then build it new. The outcome is still the same. I do not use springfox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How I run Swagger in SpringBoot 3.2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588397/how-i-run-swagger-in-springboot-3-2-0)

Comment: @Mohamedaminebenhassen I already saw that post, I also tried the version 2.4.0 without success. I do not have an extra class as swagger config. The project was newly set up with spring initializr.